# curl: (7) Failed to connect to [external site] port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: networking, server, curl

I'm trying to fetch data (using curl) from another machine at an address with port 8080, however the connection is being refused.

```
[04:18 PM]-[vagrant@u1404php56]-[~] 
$ curl "http://externalsite:8080"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to externalsite port 8080: Connection refused
```

(where `externalsite` is the address of the other machine)

ping `externalsite` is successful so it can be reached.

How do I get my machine to allow me to talk to the other machine on port 8080?

I would need the solution to work for using curl and I need to use 8080.

Thanks.

(I'm running both this machine and the other machine as VMs on the same host, but I would think that a solution would work for this scenario or if the machines are 'real' and on separate physical locations)

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, Connection Refused could mean that nothing is listening on the specified port.

Comment: How are the network interfaces configured  for both VMs? Are they bridged? NATed? Localhost Only?  Are VMs on the same subnet?

Comment: Terrance if I put http://externalsite:8080 in the browser then the page loads. So the externalsite does have something there.

Comment: @Terrance And if I issue the exact same curl command from my Mac, this works perfectly.

Comment: Also, if I issue just `curl "http://externalsite"` from the VM then this loads fine. But I need what is at 8080, which is different server, and as you can see from my comments above, both the web browser on the host machine and the Mac OS terminal can access it.

Comment: @meccooll both VMs are NAT

Comment: Sorry but the following makes no sense. "if I put externalsite:8080 in the browser then the page loads" "if I issue the exact same curl command from my Mac, this works perfectly" "if I issue just curl "http://externalsite" from the VM then this loads fine".  how does http://externalsite work? do you also have something listening on port 80 ? If it works from browser that means it should work with curl try `telnet externalsite 8080`